# Create a lisf of 5 latest articles

Tags: list, article

I have a custom-built PHP/MySql website and on the homepage it has a list of the latest premium articles (called Summaries). The problem is that after several months of posting content, the homepage becomes longer than it should be. How do I limit the number of posts down to 5, say the newest 5 posts? Here's the code that generates the ever-growing list of articles with thumbnail, Contine Reading etc. Thanks!

```
                  <div id="summaries">

                 <?php if($summaries){ 
                   $count=0;
                   foreach($summaries as $article) {
                   $date_string = date('F j, Y',strtotime($article['art_date_added']));
                   $author_name = $article['adm_full_name'];
                   if($article['art_excerpt'])
                   {
                     $excerpt = substr(strip_tags($article['art_excerpt']),0,340).'[...]' ; 
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     $excerpt = substr(strip_tags($article['art_content']),0,340).'[...]' ;   
                   }
                    if($count % 2 == 0)
                      {
                         $even = TRUE;  
                      }
                      else
                      {
                         $even=FALSE;  
                      }
                    $count++;
                 ?>
                 <?php if($even) { ?>                    
                 <article class="article">
                    <a href="<?=$article['permalink']; ?>" class="listThumbnail">
                    <?php if(!$article['art_image']) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>site_images/website_images/default.png" width="120px" class=""/></a>
                    <?php }else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?=$article['art_image']; ?>" width="120px" class=""/></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <header class="col-lg-9">
                       <a href="<?=$article['permalink']; ?>"><h2><?=$article['art_title']; ?></h2></a>
                       <div class="meta">
                        Posted by <b><?php echo $article['adm_full_name']; ?></b> on <?=$date_string; ?></em> 
                        | <b><?=$article['comments_total']; ?> comments</b></div>
                       <p>
                         <?=$excerpt; ?>
                         <a href="<?=$article['permalink']; ?>" class="cr">Continue Reading </a>
                       </p>
                    </header>
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>   
                 </article>

                 <?php } ?>

                 <?php if(!$even) { ?>
                 <article class="article">
                    <a href="<?=$article['permalink']; ?>" class="listThumbnailR">
                    <?php if(!$article['art_image']) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>site_images/website_images/default.png" width="120px" class=""/></a>
                    <?php }else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?=$article['art_image']; ?>" width="120px" class=""/></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <header class="col-lg-9">
                       <a href="<?=$article['permalink']; ?>"><h2><?=$article['art_title']; ?></h2></a>
                       <div class="meta">
                        Posted by <b><?php echo $article['adm_full_name']; ?></b> on <?=$date_string; ?></em> 
                        | <b><?=$article['comments_total']; ?> comments</b></div>
                       <p>
                         <?=$excerpt; ?>
                         <a href="<?=$article['permalink']; ?>" class="cr">Continue Reading </a>
                       </p>
                    </header>
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>   
                 </article>

                 <?php } ?>
                 <?php }} ?>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to limit the data sent from server to the client. I suppose you are using a query to pull all records (or more records than 5). Just use a `LIMIT` clause in your query or in your ORM query code to return latest 5 items.

Comment: yes, that's what Im thinking, so in theory I understand what needs to be done... but where in the code do I add the limit of 5 is what's troubling me. Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't shown the code where `$summaries` is assigned value. It is an array and must be coming from your database access code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the deal was to set up a counter and limit it to 5 latest texts from the given Summaries category of texts. Here's the full code that works as expected

```
                 <?php if($summaries){ 
                   $count=0;

                   foreach($summaries as $article) {
                   if($count>=5){ break; } // Choose number of summaries shown in homepage
                   $date_string = date('F j, Y',strtotime($article['art_date_added']));
                   $author_name = $article['adm_full_name'];
                   if($article['art_excerpt'])
                   {
                     $excerpt = substr(strip_tags($article['art_excerpt']),0,340).'[...]' ; 
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     $excerpt = substr(strip_tags($article['art_content']),0,340).'[...]' ;   
                   }
                    if($count % 2 == 0)
                      {
                         $even = TRUE;  
                      }
                      else
                      {
                         $even=FALSE;  
                      }
                    $count++;
                 ?>
                 <?php if($even) { ?>                    
                 <article class="article">
                    <a href="<?=$article['permalink']; ?>" class="listThumbnail">
                    <?php if(!$article['art_image']) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>site_images/website_images/default.png" width="120px" class=""/></a>
                    <?php }else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?=$article['art_image']; ?>" width="120px" class=""/></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <header class="col-lg-9">
                       <a href="<?=$article['permalink']; ?>"><h2><?=$article['art_title']; ?></h2></a>
                       <div class="meta">
                        Posted by <b><?php echo $article['adm_full_name']; ?></b> on <?=$date_string; ?></em> 
                        | <b><?=$article['comments_total']; ?> comments</b></div>
                       <p>
                         <?=$excerpt; ?>
                         <a href="<?=$article['permalink']; ?>" class="cr">Continue Reading </a>
                       </p>
                    </header>
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>   
                 </article>

                 <?php } ?>

                 <?php if(!$even) { ?>
                 <article class="article">
                    <a href="<?=$article['permalink']; ?>" class="listThumbnailR">
                    <?php if(!$article['art_image']) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>site_images/website_images/default.png" width="120px" class=""/></a>
                    <?php }else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?=$article['art_image']; ?>" width="120px" class=""/></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <header class="col-lg-9">
                       <a href="<?=$article['permalink']; ?>"><h2><?=$article['art_title']; ?></h2></a>
                       <div class="meta">
                        Posted by <b><?php echo $article['adm_full_name']; ?></b> on <?=$date_string; ?></em> 
                        | <b><?=$article['comments_total']; ?> comments</b></div>
                       <p>
                         <?=$excerpt; ?>
                         <a href="<?=$article['permalink']; ?>" class="cr">Continue Reading </a>
                       </p>
                    </header>
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>   
                 </article>

                 <?php } ?>
                 <?php }} ?>
              </div>
```